# SharePoint 2013 Picture Library Preview Image will not Display

Tags: sharepoint-online, picture-library, image-display, thumbnail, preview

I've been struggling with this issue for a while. I am unable to get the image to show on the preview section of the Picture Library. I've checked to ensure the content type was correctly set and also that the thumbnail images we're being created. I ran out of ideas, is there anyway to reset the picture link of the thumbnail image so it points to the proper thumbnail picture?

[image: Image Stored in Picture Library]

[image: Image when opened in Display or Edit Mode]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your attached screenshot. It looks like you are not using `Picture Library`,and You may use a document library and you have allowed content type and add the `Picture content type` or any something else.

What proves that this is not a default `Picture Library` : in default, you can find `New Picture` link rather than `new document`.

[image]

So If you don't have any reason to do that , I suggest to create a new `Picture Library` by adding a new app > `Picture Library` that should be working properly.

Comment: A (Classic) Picture Library has JSLinks defined on the Thumbsnails View (which, judging by the name, does something to create a tileview), maybe if you apply those scripts to a Document Library View it does its work as well.. the JSLinked files are is: ``sp.ui.tileview.js;callout.js``

Comment: Thanks @Danny'365CSI'Engelman for your useful clarification , really appreciate that :)

Comment: Thanks for the input team, i deleted the picture library and added a new library which seems to do the same thing. I am creating these libraries from the default app. Settings > Site Contents > Add an App > Picture Library. All my picture libraries show up as + new document.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Issue 2]

After searching for a solution I've located the actual problem. If you look at the attached picture you'll see that the link to the thumbnail preview seems to be broken which is why i get the black boxed "X".

So now my new issue is figuring out how to reset or get the script working so that it can pull the proper image from the library.

Comment: By they way, these are two different site collections.

Answer (score 0):

activate SharePoint server publishing feature and it will resolve to the correct preview image url.